# Adding Previous and Next Month Functionality to Calendar Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

So what I'm trying to do is generate a calendar report in Report Builder based on the start and end dates entered. Based on this, I want to use buttons below the calendar called "Previous Month" and "Next Month" that on-click, will go to the previous or next months' calendar based on the start and end dates entered. I've tried doing this with a sub-report (report calls itself with new parameter values), but after one button click back or forwards, it starts decrementing or incrementing by year instead of month. Is there any way to do this? I'm trying to make this previous month/next month toggle work like that of Micorsoft Outlook's Month View.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What makes it decrement by year instead of month?  How are the new parameter values getting set?

Comment: For example, when the previous month button is clicked, there's a Go to report Action that passes in the start date parameter as =dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Parameters!start_cymd.Value),month(Parameters!start_cymd.Value),1)) and the end date parameter as =dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Parameters!end_cymd.Value),month(Parameters!end_cymd.Value),0))

Comment: Are users allowed to choose partial months' data?   Like June 1 - June 10?   or do they always get a full month?

Comment: Right now they always get a full month based on what start and end dates they input.

Comment: If they _always_ get a full calendar month, I find it easier to only provide one parameter, e.g `MonthStart` and calculate end of month from that same date. @TabAlleman shows a good example of this in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx), you are using incorrect syntax in your expressions, which makes me wonder how it's even working at all.

Your DateAdd should use the DateInterval enum, and I'm not sure why you even need to use DateSerial, but it should have its hard-coded parameters in double-quotes.

Seems to me that this expression should work for what you need:

```
=dateadd(DateInterval.Month,-1,Parameters!start_cymd.Value)
```

But that's assuming, as per your comment, that the users can only choose a full month's data, so the start_cymd parameter will always be the first of the month.

Getting the end date is trickier because different months have different end-dates.   Here's an example from the same MSDN page:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Parameters!start_cymd.Value), Month(Parameters!start_cymd.Value), "1").AddDays(-1)
```

These should get the start and end date of the previous month.  Reverse the math/logic to get the next month.

Comment: Hi Tab, this works--except when the report calls itself the second time, it starts decrementing by a year and the month stays constant. In other words: Calendar is generated for start date (January 2015), report calls itself through go to report action with the two dates above being passed in as parameters which spits out December 2014 (correct), report calls itself a second time and now returns December 2013 (not correct) and continues in this pattern every time it is called. Any idea whats causing this behavior?

Comment: No idea.   It doesn't seem possible if everything is exactly as you describe it.   I would need to see it happening to have some idea how to debug it.   Can you put in something that will display the value of `start_cymd` on each iteration?

Comment: Honestly don't know what I did, but now it seems to be working. Thanks for all of your help!